# Ничего не выводит при выполнении этой программы

Tags: python

когда `message` больше,чем `key`, то ничего не выводит, а когда меньше или одинаково по длине, то все работает. Как можно это исправить?

```
while message:
    if len(message)>len(key):
        key=key[0:]
    else:
        e=key[0]
        if e.isupper():
            e=alf.index(e)
            g=message[0]
            if g.isupper():
                g=alf.index(g)
                y=(g+e)%33
                d=alf[y]
                s1+=d
            else:
                g=alf2.index(g)
                y=(g+e)%33
                d=alf2[y]
                s1+=d
        else:
            e=alf2.index(e)
            g=message[0]
            if g.isupper():
                g=alf.index(g)
                y=(g+e)%33
                d=alf[y]
                s1+=d               
            else:
                g=alf2.index(g)
                y=(g+e)%33
                d=alf2[y]
                s1+=d
    message=message[1:]
    key=key[1:]
return(s1)
```

Answer (score 1):

А какой результат вы ожидали? Именно так и написан показанный скрипт. 
Ничего, кроме

```
key=key[0:]
message=message[1:]
key=key[1:]
```

при превышении длины message над длиной key и не выполняется. Ну представте, что изначально это так - вы уменьшаете одновременно оба списка. И что дальше? Это соотношение не измениться никогда. Кстати

```
key=key[0:]
```

вообще загадочный оператор.

К чему относиться return(s1)? И каково начальное значение s1?

Кроме того, совсем непонятно, что в вашем представлении означает слово "выводит", так как ни одного оператора вывода в вашем фрагменте кода не наблюдается.

В общем - не скрипт, а полная загадка.

Comment: у меня return грубо говоря является выводом, потому что мне надо вывести в созданном окне, изначальное значение s1-' '

Comment: Я ничего не понял, но знаю, что return никогда и ни в каком языке программирования  не является оператором вывода. А исключительно оператором возврата.

Comment: он мне возвращает результат который я в созданном окне вывожу,все правильно, просто как мне исправить именно эту часть, чтобы если длина message больше длины key, работала исправно

Comment: Что значит "правильно(исправно)"?

Comment: Чтобы он вывел правильный результат, сейчас он просто ничего не выводит

Comment: @Tiranich В этом ответе всё правильно написано, при выполнении этого условия у вас цикл в итоге ничего в s1 никогда не запишет, что там было, то и останется и вернётся из функции в итоге

Comment: @Tiranich Это вы так непринужденно троллите? Я вас спросил, какой результат вы считаете правильным. Еще раз - если при входе в ваш цикл условие len(message)>len(key) не выполняется, то НИЧЕГО кроме  перечисленных в моем ответе трех операторов не выполняется, а и из этих трех первый - вообще бессмысленный (т.е. не делает ничего). При этом соотношение длин message и key нигде и никогда не измениться.  Что при этом он должен "вывести"? Что принял на вход, то и "вывел".

Comment: мне надо, чтобы после первого цикла key принимало первоначальное значение

Comment: @Tiranich if len(message)>len(key): return (s1)  Еще (третий) раз: если при входе в цикл это отношение исполняется есть, то оно (отношение) у вас не измениться никогда. И вернет то s1, что и было при входе. А при использовании указанного оператора вместо вашего  - и не изменит key.